# Combine two columns containing lists of first and last names into one column that has a list of full names

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has many columns. Two of them are `first` and `last`, which contain lists of first and last names, respectively. Some of the names are missing and have blank strings in their place. But the first item in the `first` list matches up with the first item in the `last` list.

```
     first                                         last
0    ['john','alex','james','mike','sarah']        ['smith','','connor','michaels','fort']  
1    ['stephen','', 'brittany', 'mandy']           ['chambers','ronalds','','moore']
2    ['guy', 'alec', 'tyrone', 'joe','','amy']     ['lafluer','baldwin','james','montana','','adams']
```

I want to combine these lists into one column to get the column `name`, which contains a list of both the first and last names. So in this example the result would be:

```
     name                                         
0    ['john smith','alex ','james ','mike michaels','sarah fort']  
1    ['stephen chambers',' ronalds', 'brittany ', 'mandy moore']
2    ['guy lafluer', 'alec baldwin', 'tyrone james', 'joe montana',' ','amy adams']
```

Combining two string columns in pandas is easy, with `df['col3'] = df['col1'] + df['col2']`, but I am not sure how to do that and get two lists together in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`zip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp)** with **[`list comprehension`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)**:

```
df['name'] = df.apply(lambda x: [m + ' ' + n for m,n in zip(x['first'], x['last'])], 1)
```

**OR**

```
df['name'] = df.apply(lambda x: [' '.join(x) for x in zip(x['first'],x['last'])], 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def combiner(l1, l2):
   return [' '.join(x) for x in zip(l1, l2)]


df["name"]=df.apply(lambda x: combiner(x["first"], x["last"]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try with two for loop

```
l=[[f +' '+ l for f,l in zip(x,y)] for x, y  in zip(df['first'],df['last'])]
Out[508]: 
[['john smith', 'alex ', 'james connor', 'mike michaels', 'sarah fort'],
 ['stephen chambers', ' ronalds', 'brittany ', 'mandy moore'],
 ['guy lafluer',
  'alec baldwin',
  'tyrone james',
  'joe montana',
  ' ',
  'amy adams']]

df['name']=l
```